# Show text and disable checkbox on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So I have two separate functions, one for disabling the second checkbox when someone clicks on the first and another function which displays some text when someone clicks on a checkbox but I can't get the two functions to play nicely together. The functions work fine on there own. The whole thing breaks when you try to use both functions:

```js
 // on click disable other text box
    function ckChange1(direct) {
      var ckName = document.getElementsByName(direct.name);
      for (var i = 0, c; c = ckName[i]; i++) {
       c.disabled = !(!direct.checked || c === direct);
      }
    }
    
    // shows text on click
    function showText() {
      const checkBox = document.getElementById("progress1");
      const text = document.getElementById("text");
      if ((checkBox.checked = true)){
            text.style.display = "block";
        } else {
           text.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
   #text{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox"  id="progress2" onclick="ckChange1(this); showText();">
    <label>DIRECT</label>    
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="progress1" onclick="ckChange1(this); showText();">
    <label>MULTI-ROUTE TYPE</label>
    
    <h2>Drop Off</h2>
    <h2 id="text">First Drop Off</h2>
```

I can't seem to figure this one out since the second function isn't changing the value of the checkbox at all rather it's just checking the value so I don't see why it would interfere with the first function.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: you are reading `direct.name` where as you have no `name` attribute in your checkboxes. As a result your `ckName` var is empty array. How is this working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I didn't understand your request
but try this

```js
function ckChange1(direct) {
 var element=document.getElementById(direct);
 var ed=element.disabled;
 element.disabled=!ed;
 showText(!ed);
}
function showText(ed) {
 const text = document.getElementById("text");
 text.style.display = ed?"block":"none";
}
```

```css
#text{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="progress2" onclick="ckChange1('progress1');">
<label>DIRECT</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="progress1" onclick="ckChange1('progress2');">
<label>MULTI-ROUTE TYPE</label>
<h2>Drop Off</h2>
<h2 id="text">First Drop Off</h2>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that! however, I just realised there's a small issue but it's entirely my fault for not explaining properly. So it should only display the text if they click on `multi-route type` checkbox if they click on direct checkbox then nothing should happen. How would I implement this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```js
function ckChange1(t) {

  var allRadios = document.getElementsByClassName('rad') ;
  var text = document.getElementById('text') ;
  
  t.checked = t.checked ? true : false ;   
  
  for( var i = 0; i < allRadios.length ; i++) {
    if (allRadios[i] != t) {
      allRadios[i].checked = false ;
      allRadios[i].disabled = t.checked ;
    }
  }
  
  text.style.display = t.checked ? "block" : "none" ;
  
}
```

```css
#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  class="rad" id="progress2" onclick="ckChange1(this)">
<label>DIRECT</label>    
    
<input type="checkbox" class="rad" id="progress1" onclick="ckChange1(this);">
<label>MULTI-ROUTE TYPE</label>
    
<h2>Drop Off</h2>
<h2 id="text">First Drop Off</h2>
```